# TestNg DataProvider not running all tests simultaneously but as batch

Tags: selenium, dataprovider, saucelabs

I am using the sauce lab for running selenium testNg java script where i have a single @Test method that accepts 250 distinct value from a @dataProvider of TestNG as input. **Expected**: To spawn 250 browser session parallel in saucelabs and execute the @Test method 250 times parallel.
**Actual**: I can see only a max of 10-12 at a time and remaining sessions follows as the running batch completes.

*Please find below my code*
POM.XML snippet:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <parallel>methods</parallel>
        <threadCount>250</threadCount>
        <data-provider-thread-count>250</data-provider-thread-count>
        <redirectTestOutputToFile>false</redirectTestOutputToFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

DataProvider Code:

```java
@DataProvider(name="SearchData", parallel=true)
public Object[][] GetSearchData() {
//Returning 2D array of Test Data
Object[][] arrayObject = readFromExcel("C:/Test_Workspace/TestData/ICJ-DataProvider.xls","Sheet1");
    return arrayObject;
}

@Test(dataProvider = "SearchData")
public void TestE2E(String hocn, String username, String password, Method method)
throws MalformedURLException, InvalidElementStateException, UnexpectedException {
    this.createDriver("chrome", "54.0", "Windows 10", method.getName());
    WebDriver driver = this.getWebDriver();
    Service.visitPage(driver, hocn, username, password);
}
```

As you can see, I am passing threadCount=250 and data-provider-thread-count=250 from pom.xml. Still it runs as a batch of 10 to complete the 250 data in data provider.

[Image showing only 10 instances at a time instead of 250](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aeiE.png)

Can some one please guide me in getting all 250 sessions up at a time?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has got nothing to do with TestNG.

You are being throttled by SauceLabs.

Quoting the SauceLabs documentation.

> Checking Your Concurrency Limit
>
> Each Sauce Labs account has a set maximum number of concurrent
>   sessions. You can find your concurrency limit on the My Account page
>   (at https://saucelabs.com/beta/users/username).  If this number does
>   not match your subscription or invoiced contract, please contact
>   Support.
>
> Subaccounts may have had their concurrency limit lowered by their
>   parent account. To access higher concurrency levels, you will need to
>   ask the person responsible for the parent account to increase your
>   limit.

For more information, please refer to the below documentation on SauceLabs portal.

1. [Why am I not getting the parallelism/concurrency I expected?](https://support.saucelabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/225243308-Why-am-I-not-getting-the-parallelism-concurrency-I-expected-)
2. [Understanding Concurrency Limits and Team Accounts](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Understanding+Concurrency+Limits+and+Team+Accounts)